# jQuery COLORBOX plugin: closing iframe and opening another (OR better: resize iframe and load diff content into it)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have an html pg I open in an iframe, it's a "send to friend" form.. 
when submit, since thank-you content is much less, I need to either 
resize the iframe (reduce the height of it) or close the iframe 
containing the form and open another frame with the thank-you 
content.. how can I do that..

I tried

```
  onCleanup:'parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()';
```

but this didn't work....

thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

This option accepts a function, so:

```
onCleanup: parent.$.fn.colorbox.close;
```

Or you can wrap it with an anonymous function.

```
onCleanup: function(){
    parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for yr response.. but I didn't pose question right.. I hadn't realized..  actually this is for onsubmit (which in my case is actually just a link) so what I need to do is bind to $("a#submitForm") so that event is triggered when click "submit" link (which, again is just a link, not a submit button..)  thank you..

Comment: sorry, hit return and published comment..

in this url, it can be seen, when hit 'submit' iframe with thank-you content opens, but iframe with the form doesn't close...  if I add this:

Comment: if I ad this

 
$("a#idSubmitEmailToFriend").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();  
 });

Comment: why does comment get submitted every time I press 'return'?? this is not too practical..  as I said, if I add above-mentioned code the iframe with the form closes but iframe with thank-you content doesn't open; i.e., I can't do custom event-binding to link that opens 2nd iframe...

Comment: here's a version in which I don't close and open iframes...  I just hide email form and show thank-you content in same iframe...
www./mayacove.com/dev/colorbox/index_mine_resize.html

all I need to know now is how to resize iframe onsubmit so it's 300px high instead of 550px.. this is my code to hide form and show thank-you content:

 $("a#idSubmitEmailToFriend").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("div#emailFriendWrapper").hide();  
  $("div#ThankYouWrapper").show();
             //  ****   need code to resize iframe here (just chg height...)   ***** 
 });

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

This may not be ideal, but you could try something like this:

Iframe code:

```
$("a#idSubmitEmailToFriend").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div#emailFriendWrapper").hide();
    parent.closePopup();
    return false;
});
```

Main page (outside the document.ready)

```
function closePopup(){
    var thankYou = '<div class="thanks">Thank you</div>';
    $('#cboxContent').html(thankYou);
    // adjust this height to match the new content
    $.fn.colorbox.resize({ height: 100 });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.fn.colorbox.close();
    }, 2000);
}
```